# Instagram public content api sunsetting on December 11th entirely?

Tags: api, tags, instagram, hashtag

Hi Instagram developers,

i was wondering if the instagram public content api will be entirely turned off on december 11th. To me, the hint from instagram is not clear.
I am using tags API for public content as well as /tags/{tags}/media/recent.

Does anybody know if this apis will still be up and usable after December 11th or if we have to move on to the new Instagram Graph API?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Everything that uses the public content permission will be closing on the 11th of December.

Instagram have released a Hashtag API in the Instagram Graph API, but it's much more limited than the old API and only Instagram business accounts can use it.